# SSIS expression similar to case statement

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I need to write an expression for derived column. My column name is 'status'. what is the equivalent expression in SSIS for the below condition?

> Case when Status Like '%Open%' then 0
>         when Status like '%Won%' then 1
>         when status like "%Lost%' then 2    Else 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a history of not accepting the answers on your questions.   You might want to work on this if you want people on the site to continue helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
FINDSTRING(Status,"Open",1) > 0 ? 0 : (FINDSTRING(Status,"Won",1) > 0 ? 1 : (FINDSTRING(Status,"Lost",1) > 0 ? 2 : 3))
```

Comment: You left out when "Lost" then 2.